# Is the [conf] token respected when publishing files using Ivy?

Tags: ant, configuration, build, ivy

I'm learning Ivy (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) and integrating it as part of our build process.  It's going pretty well, but I'm stuck on something with the Ivy publish task.  Specifically, I'd like to publish to the local repository with the following pattern (which includes the name of the current configuration):

**${ivy.local.default.root}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]**

So I set up my custom resolver:

```
<filesystem name="modifiedLocalRepo">
    <ivy pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" />
    <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" />
</filesystem>
```

And configured the publish task:

```
<ivy:publish 
    settingsRef="ivy.ext.settings.custom" <!--Location of definition of modifiedLocalRepo-->
    resolver="modifiedLocalRepo" 
    artifactspattern="bin/Debug/[module].[ext]" 
    pubrevision="1.1-Test" 
    overwrite="true"
    conf="primary"
/>
```

And have the conf defined in the ivy.xml file:

```
<info organisation="Mine" module="Dependency"/>
<configurations defaultconf="primary"> <!--Don't think defaultconf should be necessary-->
    <conf name="primary"/>
</configurations>
<publications>
    <artifact name="Dependency" ext="dll" type="bin" conf="primary"/>
    <artifact name="Dependency" ext="pdb" type="bin" conf="primary"/>
</publications>
```

I have the process working, ivy configured, resolved, the project building, and the artifacts published (using my custom resolver above).  But the [conf] token is always resolving to "default."  So the published directory has the structure:

**\.ivy2\local\Mine\Dependency\1.1-Test\bins\default\**

instead of the structure

**\.ivy2\local\Mine\Dependency\1.1-Test\bins\primary\**

I've been tinkering around with it, setting the conf value, defaultconf value, etc. everywhere they are valid but it's always "default."

I'm using ant to do the build, and have run in debug mode (-d), inspected the output and noticed nothing useful.  I've looked through the output of <echoproperties\> and noticed nothing useful.  I've read through the Ivy documentation and only found use of [conf] as a token in retrieve and report output.

I can attach the full xml files I'm using to do my limited test build if it would be useful.

Is the [conf] token valid/respected in the artifact pattern for an Ivy publish?  If so, what am I missing?  Thanks!

**Update:**
Was using Ivy 2.3.0-rc2 and decided to try to roll back and use Ivy 2.0.0.  Same issue.

Comment: it should work, could you try an ant -v (verbose) and see if you find anything curious?

Comment: Just ran in verbose and found that the ivy:publish output is loading the default ivy.properties file from the ivy-2.3.0-rc2.jar file and then declares "Override ignored for property 'ivy.configurations'" (along with others).  That output was there when I ran in debug, but I missed it *chagrin.*  But the value of ivy.configurations is "*" which I would think would work.

Also, I checked and ivy.resolved.configurations is set to "primary" before the ivy:publish.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my Ivy project in [github](http://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir). I set it up, so you can easily add it into an existing Ant project.

We use a Maven repository, so I have it setup to create a `pom.xml`, and then use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy it back to the Maven repository. We use Jenkins for our build, so we use Jenkins to run the `mvn deploy-file` to do the deployment. I guess we could use `<ivy:publish>`, but never really tried it.

Comment: Took a look through the project.  Unfortunately it doesn't help much since I am specifically needing to know about Ivy's publish with [conf].  You use [conf] only as part of a retrieve pattern, which I knew worked from the Ivy examples.  But the project itself will be great to review as a much more in-depth Ivy example. Thanks!